# Find $E(X)$ for random variable $X$: the number of seconds it took a frog to reach its target

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

A jumping frog is currently at $x=0$ and $t=0$(time). With each second, the frog jumps to the right to its target, by randomly choosing the leap length from $\{0, 1, \dots, n\}$.

We want to find the time it takes the frog to get out of the region $[0, n-1]$. Let $X$ be a random variable denoting the number of seconds it took the frog to reach at least $n$.

Find $E[X]$ (the expectation of $X$).

So, first of all I know that $$E[X] = \sum_{i=0}^\infty P(X\ge i)$$
$$P(X\ge i) = 1 - P(X<i)$$
Is this true?
We can loot at the total number of steps as the sum of steps at each second $i$.
So we use elementary combinatorics and it leads us to this:
$$X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_{i-1} \le n-1$$
$$P(X\ge i) = \frac{n+i-2 \choose n-1}{(i-1)^{n+1}} $$
I also tried calculating the sum but it didn't go anywhere.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $j\in\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$ let $E_j$ denote the expected time it takes for the spider to reach at least $n$ given the spider resides at position $j$. You're trying to find $E_0$. Using the total law of expectation with recursion we get $$E_j=1+\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=j}^{n-1}E_k$$ This system of $n$ equations boils down to $$E_j=\Bigg(\frac{n}{n+1}\Bigg)^jE_0$$ $$E_{n-1}=\frac{n+1}{n}$$ Combining the two gives us an expression for $E_0$: $$E_0=\Bigg(\frac{n+1}{n}\Bigg)^n \longrightarrow e$$ as $n\longrightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Alternatively, one could take the limit from the start, so we'd have continuos leap lenghts in (say) $[0,1]$ , so that if $g(x)$ is the expected time to get out of the unit interval, we have the recursion $g(x) = 1 + \int_{x}^1 g(t) dt $ with $\lim_{x \to 1^-} g(x)=1$, and the solution $g(x)=\exp(1-x)$

Comment: $g(x)$ is the expected time to get out of the unit interval starting at $x\in[0,1]$, correct?

Comment: Exactly........

Comment: I don't think what you're saying is true. Let $f$ be any pdf  with support contained in $[0,\infty)$. Set $X_0=x\in[0,1)$ and, for $n\geq 1$, define $$X_n=X_{n-1}+Q_{n}$$ where $Q_1,Q_2,\ldots\sim f$ are independent. Define a random variable $N$ by $$N=\min\{j\in \mathbb{N}|X_j\geq1\}$$ Now set $$g(x)=\mathbb{E}(N|X_0=x)$$ Using the total law of expectation we have $$g(x)=\int_0^{\infty}\mathbb{E}(N|X_0=x,Q_1=t)f(t)dt=1+\int_0^{1-x}g(x+t)f(t)dt$$ This becomes $$g'(x)=-f(1-x)$$ For example, if $Q_1,Q_2,\ldots \sim \mathcal{U}[0,1]$ then $g(x)=-x+2$ making $g(0)=2$ which makes more sense....?